# Как сделать консоль для текстового редактора

Tags: python, tkinter, консоль

Недавно начал писать текстовый редактор. При нажатии на кнопку "run" запускается нужный пользователю файл.

```
os.startfile("Some_file.py")
```

Также есть лэйбл в который хотелось бы выводить ошибки (ну и прочий вывод). То есть выводить все данные в этот лэйбл.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
def start():
   os.startfile("some_file.py")
root=Tk()
Button1=Button(root,text="run", command=start)
Button1.pack()
Label1=Label(root,text="")
Label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Но я абсолютно не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: но консоль подразумевает и ввод. или нужен только вывод ?

Comment: Ввод у меня записан в файл (в данном случае " some_file.py") . Мне хотелось бы записать вывод данного скрипта в Label1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В питоне есть такая вещь как `redirect_stdout` ...

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
f = io.StringIO()

try:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        exec(workplace.get(0.0, END))
        label1.configure(text=f.getvalue())

except Exception as e:
    em = traceback.format_exc()
    label1.configure(text=traceback.format_exc())
```